# Ubuntu: How to set up an init script that only runs on the first boot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scripting, boot, init.d

I need to install an init script that only runs on the first boot after it's installation. How can I accomplish that on Ubuntu?

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: I need it for an EC2 AMI. I want to make certain modifications depending on the provided user-data.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a trick like this to avoid executing the script more than once:

```
#!/bin/bash
test ! -e /path/to/chosen/file || exit 0
touch /path/to/chosen/file
echo "Executing my job"
```

You can run the above script only once. Other executions will exit because the file should be created in the first execution. Of course, you need to have enough permissions to create the file.

To keep this valid after reboot, you need to avoid creating the file under a temporary file system like `/tmp`. Also, this prevent multiple execution of the script regardless of whether it is executed manually or part of startup process.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few tools within the oem-config packages to carry out initial configuration immediately following installation.